# What's wrong with my conditional comment?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have IE 11.
I'm making the following conditional comment for my html:

```
    <!--[if (lt IE 9)]>
        <div style="background-color: black; width: 200px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <![endif]-->
```

Then I'm trying to check if it works via IE built-in emulation, setting both document mode and user agent string options to IE 8 or IE 7.
The block in the comment is not displayed, but the comment disappears at the same time from html.

Is it something wrong with the code or with emulation?

Comment: IE11 doesn't support conditional comments, not even in any emulating mode. Among some other old APIs, support for [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was dropped in IE10, and more [legacy APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacyAPIs) are obsoleted in IE11. In IE11 these changes mostly reflect to emulating modes too. But don't worry, your conditional comments are still working in real IE<9 : ).

Answer (score 1):

Remove brackets

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <div style="background-color: black; width: 200px; height: 400px;"></div>
 <![endif]-->
```

is enough

There is a great article by Paul Irish, [conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) it is worth reading for sure.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having brackets. Absolutely nowhere in that link is it stated that brackets are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks! But I still have the same problem without the brackets.

Comment: @rumirumi if conditional style not helping you use it with javascript refer [check-ie-version](http://www.jquery4u.com/browsers-2/check-ie-version/) for more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying **Teemu**'s comment in this answer as community wiki, because it's what I was looking for since few days... and I think this is the right answer here.

> IE11 doesn't support conditional comments, not even in any emulating
>   mode. Among some other old APIs, support for [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was
>   dropped in IE10, and more [legacy APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacyAPIs) are obsoleted in IE11. In IE11
>   these changes mostly reflect to emulating modes too. But don't worry,
>   your conditional comments are still working in real IE<9 : )

THANK YOU Teemu !

By the way, there's a software wich understands IE conditional comments while IE 11 can't anymore : it's [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). Will be really useful now...